# Using session variables to store expanding lists

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, session-variables

I'm working on an application where a user can input data: using an example, they can input a product name, a description, and a price. There are also two buttons: one button, "Add new product", will allow them to temporarily save all of the product data (NOT to the database) and allow them to input another information on a product; the other button, "Save changes", will save all of those products that were added via "Add new product".

I'm completely new with session variables, but they look pretty similar to Viewbag/Tempdata/etc. But I'm trying to figure out if I can make a list from a session variable, and add a product to the list as the user presses "Add new product" until they hit "Save changes". Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a little hack for this. In my view model, I made a counter variable to keep track of the products and incremented it whenever the controller got called (IE, 1 for the first product they're adding, 2 for the second, etc.). So once the controller gets called when they click on the Add New Product button, I pass in the view model and check the counter variable. If it's == 1, I make a new list, append that item, and make a session variable equal to the list. Otherwise, if it's greater, I get the session variable that contains the list, append the item, and re-set the session variable.

Probably needs to be cleared out at some point, but I'm getting there and this seems to work so far.

Answer (score 0):

Better to save all information in array variable through jquery. When you need to "Save changes" pass array variable to your controller.
May be it will helpful for you [LINK](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/782407/How-do-I-post-array-to-MVC-controller-action-by-JQ)